# Cannot execute properly "apt-get update" when installing MongoDB under Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, ubuntu, apt-get

i'm trying to install MongoDB underr my Ubuntu 15.04 , i fulfilled those steps :

1. import the MongoDB public GPG Key:

   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
2. create the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list list-file to get the package from debian wheezy repository

   echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
3. Now when trying to execute `apt-get update`  i got this error :

> Atteint http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease Réception
>   de : 1 http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease
>   79% [1 InRelease gpgv 109 B] [Attente des fichiers d'en-tête] [Attente
>   des ficSplitting up
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.mongodb.org_apt_debian_dists_wheezy_mIgn
>   http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease
>   E: Erreur de GPG : http://repo.mongodb.org wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0
>   InRelease : Le fichier signé en clair n'est pas valable, ce qui a été
>   reçu est « NODATA ». Peut-être le réseau nécessite-t-il une
>   authentification.

i ve checked my sources files  , and its contains this :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)]/ utopic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ vivid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ utopic partner
```

Since i haven't know the problem origin , and how to solve it , **any suggestions ??**

Answer (score -2):

Try,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You're now running the command as administration, so it might help.

Comment: of course that doesn't work , there is problem in GPG  sources